# Retrieve information from database in a MessageBox | IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a GetProduct method that is supposed to return the product code, description, and price in a MessageBox. Currently, I am only able to display the word "Price" with a title on the box **"IndexOutOfBoundsException"** when it actually finds a product matching the code. If not, it displays that it is not found.

Here is the code:

```
        public static Product GetProduct(string code)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection();

        string select = @"SELECT ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice FROM Products WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";

        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(select, connection);


        SqlParameter pCode = new SqlParameter();
        pCode.ParameterName = "@ProductCode";
        pCode.Value = product.Code;
        SqlParameter pDesc = new SqlParameter();
        pDesc.ParameterName = "@Description";
        pDesc.Value = product.Description;
        SqlParameter pPrice = new SqlParameter();
        pPrice.ParameterName = "@UnitPrice";
        pPrice.Value = product.Price;

        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", code);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader prodReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

            if (prodReader.Read())
            {
                product.Code = prodReader["ProductCode"].ToString(); ;
                product.Description = prodReader["Description"].ToString();
                product.Price = ((decimal)prodReader["Price"]);

                return product;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: The field is named UnitPrice, you try to read from an indexer called Price, Is it a typo or is it your real problem?

Comment: @Steve I bet that is _exactly_ the OP's issue

Comment: Thanks @Steve, silly error on my part. Now to try and figure out the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a field named *UnitPrice* while the reader's string indexer used is named *Price*. This produces the *IndexOutOfRangeException*.
While this is a common typo it is interesting to know why this happens.

Internally the string indexer for the data reader contains this code

```
override public object this[string name] {
    get {
        return GetValue(GetOrdinal(name));
    }
}
```

As you can see it uses the [GetOrdinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx) public method to retrieve the index of the field from its name. However, if the name passed is not found the call to GetOrdinal returns -1 and of course this is not a valid index on the underlying fields array going from 0 to [FieldCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx) - 1